# Chunks are missing while streaming the response data in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, stream, axios

After getting the response from axios, I am converting it into stream.After getting some chunks `stream.on("end"` is executing. Due to this I am getting

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token with JSON.parse
```

For the normal data (response from the API) it's working. But for huge responses the chunks are missing.

I also tried to save the chunks in array, but no use. For the same API I tried with **Postman** and I am getting the response.

```
  httpRequest["responseType"] = "stream"
  httpRequest["responseEncoding"] = "utf8"
  returnValue = await axios(httpRequest)
  let outputString = "";
  const stream = returnValue.data;
  stream.on("data", (chunk) => {
       outputString += chunk.toString("utf8")
  });
  stream.on("end", () => {
  var finalJson = JSON.parse(outputString);
  });
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `responseType: 'json'`? You gain nothing from using the stream response type since you're buffering the data anyway.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Its huge data(nearly 15k records). I am getting as chunks from the api.

Comment: ...and buffering them to `outputString` only to `JSON.parse()` it yourself. I see no benefit to using a stream here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After adding Accept-Encoding as gzip, I am getting the complete response without using streams.

```
httpRequest.headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate, br"
returnValue = await axios(httpRequest)
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(returnValue.data)))
```